# Get class name from a module

Tags: ruby, inheritance

How I can get from a module the Class name of the class the module is included ?

```
module ActMethods
  def some_method(*attr_names)
    cls = self.class # this doesn't work 
  end
end
```

How I can get into the cls variable the name of the class to with this module is loaded ?

Comment: Should be working! May be you need self.class.name

Comment: Note that if the class being extended in anonymous, then printing out self.class or self.class.name returns blank, which can be confusing. This this case, it's also good to check self.class.superclass.

Comment: `self.class` isn't working for me.  `self.class.name` returns "Module".  I think it has to do with the fact that the class in which my module is included inherits from ActiveRecord::Base (Rails 3.2.8) but I'm not sure why or how that's interfering.

Comment: Figured it out, and I was correct about it relating to ActiveRecord.  See [this article on ActiveSupport::Concern](https://gist.github.com/1014971)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`self.class` does get you the class of the object the method is called on. Assuming the module was included into a class, this either is the class that included the module or a subclass thereof. If you really just want the name, you can use `self.class.name` instead.

If you extended a class with the module and you want to get that class, you can just do `cls = self` (or `cls = name` if you want the name of the class as a string).

If none of the above helps, you should clarify what you want.

Answer (score 9):

if `self` is not an option for some reason, alternative might be `ancestors`  http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors

```
# rails concern example: 

module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    p "Wooo hoo, it's  #{top_ancestor_class}"
  end 

  module ClassMethods
    def top_ancestor_class
      ancestors.first
    end
  end
end 

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end

#=> Woo hoo, it's Event(....)
```

Comment: BTW more info in my article http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/13-ruby-ancestors-descendants-and-other-annoying-relatives

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. As sepp said you have to include it for it to work.

```
module ActMethods
  def some_method(*attr_names)
    cls = self.class # this doesn't work 
    puts cls
  end
end

class Boh
  include ActMethods
end

b = Boh.new
b.some_method
```

Answer (score 1):

PS: For the general case answer, see sepp2k's answer.

If you included the module in controllers only, you might want to consider using `controller_name.classify` to get the name of the corresponding model. Example:

```
>> ArticlesController.controller_name.classify
=> "Article"
```

From there you could get the actual class (if you want), by calling `.constantize` on the result.