# How do I get the name of a class extending a module, from the module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, activerecord

I have the following model in my /app/models folder:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "dashboard"
  extend Dashboard
  
# ...
end
```

I then have in my /lib folder a file named dashboard.rb, which has the following code:

```
module Dashboard
  def self.my_function
    # --> My question pertains to what I need to put here...
  end
end
```

I'd like to write a line of code in `MyModel::Dashboard.my_function` so that it will return the name of my model (in this case `MyModel`).

I did find some information on [Get class name from a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812600/get-class-name-from-a-module) and https://gist.github.com/1014971, but it seems like when my model inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, it's different. The latter of these articles supposedly explains this, but I'm at a loss.

I tried some permutations with `superclass.name` from within `Dashboard.my_function`, but I just get `Dashboard` or `Module` returned, and not `MyModel`.

Anyone who can shed light on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do your methods have to be class methods (..can you make the my_function call from an instance of MyModel -> MyModel.first.my_function) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `extend`, you are making the module methods class methods of your `MyModel` class. Try this:

```
module Dashboard
  def my_function
    self.name
  end
end


class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  require "dashboard"
  extend Dashboard

  # ...
end
```

And rather than calling it as `MyModel::Dashboard.my_function` you would just call it directly on your model class -> `MyModel.my_function` would return `MyModel`